# Edit sketch after extrusion

Tags: dimensions, solidworks, sketching

Is there a way to do some minor changes in sketches after you have already done extrusion or any other stuff?

For example: I made a part and in the end I found that there are some unnecessary dimensions or centerlines that I want to delete(they appear in the drawing later, it annoys).

If I just try to edit it and save, it then refuses to re-do all the stuff like extrusion and icons for these things become grayed-out in the feature manager tree.

Answer (score 0):

You delete sketch entities if the extrude feature depends on them.  Just hide the sketch.